# Wrong occluding relation of objects in 3D graphics in Mathematica 12

Tags: graphics3d, display, rendering

I want to mark the intersection of lines with a spherical node with the following simple code:

```
Graphics3D[{  Black, Thick, 
Line[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], 
Line[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}], 
Line[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}],  
{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.1] }}]
```

In the Mac version of Mathematica 12, the plot displays correctly (the first figure), namely the crossing point of the lines is obscured inside the sphere.
However, in the Windows version of Mathematica 12, the lines appear as **in front of** the sphere, as shown in the second figure, consequently, the crossing point of the lines inside the sphere is wrongly exposed.
If I export the image in PNG or JPG format, the problem also exists in the obtained image file.

Is it a bug of the Windows version of Mathematica 12? Can it be solved?

Note: The problem is not caused by the setting of Opacity. In the Windows version, the sphere is totally opaque (Opacity=1).

Plot in Mac version:

[image]

Plot in Windows version:

[image]

Comment: This is z-fighting I think

Comment: Try switching to a different rendering engine on Windows like "OpenGL" or "Mesa" with: `RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "Mesa"}`, or try changing the depth sorting to use BSPTrees instead of z-buffering: `RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingMethod" -> "BSPTree"}`

Comment: @flinty Many thanks. The problem is solved by changing 3DRenderingMethod to BSPTree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224206/wrong-occluding-relation-of-objects-in-3d-graphics-in-mathematica-12/250966#comment570864_224206):

> @flinty Many thanks. The problem is solved by changing 3DRenderingMethod to BSPTree. – zrysky Jun 18 '20 at 14:28

Answer (score 0):

I get

```
Graphics3D[{{Black, Thick, Line[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], 
   Line[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}], 
   Line[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}, {Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.1]}}]
```

[image: output]

```
Graphics3D[{{Black, Thick, Line[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], 
   Line[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}], 
   Line[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}, {Opacity[0.5], Red, 
   Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.1]}}]
```

[image: output]

It is the built-in `Opacity` that makes the difference not the OS. My pictures are all done on MacOSx with Mathematica 12.0. It is possible to add Opacity to `$DisplayFunction` and have this automatic. So check for `$DisplayFunction`. Or just always add `Opacity` to the graphics directives.

Mind the extra curly brackets!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is not caused by the setting of Opacity. In the Windows version, the sphere is totally opaque (Opacity=1).